# Generic keyCompare method

Tags: c++

please look through the following program..

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char *key1 = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*26);
    char *key2 = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*26);


    int intkey1 = 10;
    int intkey2 = 10;

    float floatkey1 = 13.5f;
    float floatkey2 = 13.5f;

    double doublekey1 = 18.5;
    double doublekey2 = 18.5;

    char charkey1[10] = "nikhil";
    char charkey2[10] = "nikhil";

    //cout<<sizeof(int)<<" "<<sizeof(float)<<" "<<sizeof(double)<<endl;

    memcpy(key1,&intkey1,sizeof(int));
    memcpy(key2,&intkey2,sizeof(int));

    int offset = sizeof(int);

    memcpy(&key1[offset],&floatkey1,sizeof(float));
    memcpy(&key2[offset],&floatkey2,sizeof(float));

    offset = offset + sizeof(float);

    memcpy(&key1[offset],&doublekey1,sizeof(double));
    memcpy(&key2[offset],&doublekey2,sizeof(double));

    offset = offset + sizeof(double);

    memcpy(&key1[offset],charkey1,sizeof(charkey1));
    memcpy(&key2[offset],charkey2,sizeof(charkey2));


    int diff = memcmp(key1,key2,26);
    if( diff > 0)
        cout<<"Key1 is greater than key2"<<endl;
    else if(diff < 0)
        cout<<"Key1 is smaller than key2"<<endl;
    else
        cout<<"Both keys are equal"<<endl;
}
```

I am developing a B+ tree for a database engine for which i need a generic keyCompare method...Is this way of comparing byte streams by memcpy always the safe and foolproof or should i need to compare based on the types of the fields present in char key that i get from scanning column information present in the database engine? IS this fastest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this way of comparing byte streams by memcpy always the safe and foolproof

It doesn't produce the correct result with integers and floats on little-endian architectures.  And it can't handle special floating point values like `inf` and `nan`.

> or should i need to compare based on the types of the fields present in char key that i get from scanning column information present in the database engine?

It should compare types using type-specific methods. For strings that involves using locales.

Answer (score 1):

All those extra allocations are not going to improve your performance, not to speak of the difficulties in writing that code correctly.

Since all the types are just primitives or arrays of primitives, you should probably just go with the straight-forward lexicographic comparison. For your ordering you only need to implement "less than", so do this lexicographically for each key. If the key is itself an array, you can use [`std::lexicographical_compare`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/lexicographical_compare/) as a primitive.